# sql: select not in

Tags: sql, mysql

how can I rewrite the following query using JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT t1Id 
    FROM table2 
);
```

Comment: not it is not, I was just curious :)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: thank you very much! but I don't understand the logic, why use "on t1.id=t2.id"? We are looking for rows in t1 which are not referenced in t2, and you tell it to join on t1.id=t2.id, which means it will join on rows that are referenced in t2... it looks somehow illogical for me

also, I noticed that the same query without "outer" works the same.. SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null

Comment: @Muhammand - the `left outer join` syntax means the rows from t1 will be returned even if the join condition to t2 fails, and the `where t2.id is null` will filter out all the rows where the join condition failed, as in those cases, t2.id will be mapped to null.

Comment: @Muhammad: if you remove the `WHERE` clause, you will see that there are `t2.id` values that are `NULL`. This is how `LEFT OUTER JOIN` works, it returns records from the table on the left, regardless of whether the join succeeds or not. We can then take advantage of that to filter by adding a `WHERE` clause that says, "show us only the records that did NOT match."

Comment: If you have many rows in t2 for each row in t1 then you'll have different output than NOT IN. NOT EXISTS is better

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT * FROM table1 t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
        SELECT *
        FROM table2 t2 
        Where t1.Id = t2.t1Id);
```

Comment: OP did specifically ask for a method using JOIN

Comment: It seems a pointless spec to me e.g. they could have said, "rewrite the following query without using the letter 'u'" and you'd have got the points instead ;)

Comment: +1 NOT EXISTS is better and safer. @Mark Baker: Whether OP asked for JOIN does not matter: should we blindly answer or aim to improve matters...? JOIN may not give the same output as NOT IN and NOT EXISTS deals with NULL (NOT IN fails)

Comment: @gbn Can you explain a bit more, please? You mean the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL` does not give same output as `NOT IN` under certain circumstances? Why?

Comment: @tombom: NOT IN, NOT EXISTS are semijoins. LEFT JOIN is an equijoin. You can get more rows from the LEFT JOIN. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4010/630 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17408/630 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966259/27535