# Using 'IN' with a sub-query in SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-in

Are there any performance issues of using "IN" keyword in SQL statements in places where we can use JOIN?

```
SELECT xxx
FROM xxx
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Id FROM xxx)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's OK to use.

You can write the query above using IN, EXISTS in all RDBMS, some also support INTERSECT.

Semantically this is a semi-join which "give me rows from table A where I have a at least one match in tableB". An INNER JOIN is "give me all matching rows"

So if TableA has 3 rows and TableB has 5 rows that match:

- an INNER JOIN is 15 rows
- a semi-join is 3 rows

This is why IN and EXISTS are pushed by me and the other SQL types here: a JOIN is wrong, requires DISTINCT and will be slower.

EXISTS support multiple column JOINs, IN doesn't in SQL Server (it does in others).

Comment: It is not ok to use. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong. I was trying to prove i was right by making you an example. However the example showed i was wrong. I appologize and removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a distinct you could use group by.  I have had cases where I got better response time using join.  Typically when I am joining all the rows via a primary key / foreign key relationship and the where is looking at a non key column.  Especially if multiple joins.  The IN can SOMETIMES force an index scan and the join will TYPICALLY use a seek if it is going to the PK.  When you design you tables line up the primary keys so they are in the same order and explicitly declare the PK / FK relationships.  Join are NOT limited to PK / FK.  But a common use of a join is to walk the PK / FK relationship and in that case my experience using a join with the keys aligned is the best performance.

Answer (score -2):

As you can read [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/tuning-joins/2/), JOINS are faster than sub-selects.

Comment: As you can read else where, JOINs are slower. http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/ The semantics are way different -1 for propogating rubbish and not knowing the difference

Comment: And your link doesn't even mention this either