# Query join and optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table INFO whose design is like this

```
id - bigint
Name - varchar2
refid - bigint
status - int
ExpDate - datetime
```

- status values can be 0,1,2,3,4
- refid is the foreign key of other table which we are going to use too

> I want to write a query where all records should come from this table with status 0, 1, 2, 3, but only 7 latest records by expdate should come whose status is 4.

I can't figure out how can we achieve this in T-SQL.

Please help me out or give me suggestion so that I can start writing it.

Upto now I have written

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFO 
WHERE STATUS IN (0,1,2,3) AND 
      REFID IN (SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW')

SELECT TOP 7
FROM INFO 
WHERE STATUS=4 AND 
      REFID IN(SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW') 
ORDER BY EXPDATE DESC
```

i need to join them??? how.. suggest and also the query

```
(SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW')
```

is coming twice how to optimize it thanks..

Comment: Do you want to optimize the query or remove duplicate records?

Comment: There are no duplicate records, because `STATUS` is different.

Comment: Ok.. the "is coming twice how to optimize it thanks.." made me think there could be duplicate records.

Comment: we are using sub queries in it.. same sub query is repeated.. i want to optimize that part

Comment: subqueries are fast or joins?

Comment: In most cases joins are more efficient.

Comment: @devarc: wrong! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966259/27535

Comment: So we are both wrong cause I've checked it and both queries have exacly the same execution plan and number of reads. Durations on profiler are nearly same.

Comment: @devarc: In which case REFTABLE is a parent of INFO : that is, you get at most 1 REFTABLE row per INFO. If you had "n" REFTABLE rows then the queries are different. Also see http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists Finally, post your script if you're so sure...

Comment: As I said in any case (1-1,1-many,mamy to many) I can see that execution plans are same. I've queried 2-3 milion record tables in many ways and always same result. Just check it. Maybe 2008r2 optimizer is more advanced than in 2005(I hope so :))

Comment: And in that link that you have pasted you have confirmation on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just UNION your 2 current queries together (you need a derived table to get the TOP though)

```
SELECT ...
FROM INFO 
WHERE STATUS IN (0,1,2,3) AND 
      REFID IN (SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW')
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM 
    (
    SELECT TOP 7 ...
    FROM INFO 
    WHERE STATUS=4 AND 
          REFID IN(SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW') 
    ORDER BY EXPDATE DESC
    ) T
```

You can get fancier, but it may not be as efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT ...,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXPDATE DESC) AS rn
    FROM INFO 
    WHERE REFID IN (SELECT REFID FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW')
    ) T
WHERE
    rn <= 7 OR STATUS <= 4
```

Comment: sub queries are efficient or joins?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to optimize this or do you want to just remove the duplicate records.

If you want to remove duplicate records then you can try using UNION-

```
SELECT * FROM INFO 
INNER JOIN REFTABLE ON INFO.refId = REFTABLE.Id
WHERE REFCHAIN = 'BMW' AND INFO.status IN (0,1,2,3)
UNION
SELECT FROM 
    (
       SELECT TOP 7 FROM INFO 
       INNER JOIN REFTABLE ON INFO.refId = REFTABLE.Id
       WHERE INFO.status=4 AND REFCHAIN='BMW'
       ORDER BY EXPDATE DESC
    ) T
```

Comment: Note that the UNION adds overhead which can be avoided using IN (or EXISTS). Reason: IN/EXISTS is a semi-join, JOIN is an equi-join. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966259/27535

Answer (score 0):

for latest 7 values in ur reftable u can use this query--

`select * from REFTABLE where REFID not in(
select top (select count(*)-7 from info) REFID from REFTABLE )`

it would have better if u could post the table structure..

Answer (score 0):

gbn and Pavanred answers about UNION solve your problem "how to join this results".
If it comes to optimization you can create temp table for results from select. Then query executes only once.

But...
I think query is too trivial to optimize this in that way.

Anyway:

```
SELECT REFID 
INTO #temp1 
FROM REFTABLE WHERE REFCHAIN='BMW'
```

And then use this in both queries like that:

```
WHERE REFID IN (SELECT REFID FROM #temp1)
```

Or like that

```
SELECT ...
FROM INFO inf
INNER JOIN #temp1 t ON inf.REFID = t.REFID
...
```