# SQL - Replacing slow "IN" statement with a JOIN

Tags: sql, performance

As per subject - I am trying to replace slow SQL IN statement with an INNER or LEFT JOIN. What I am trying to get rid of:

```
SELECT 
    sum(VR.Weight) 
FROM 
    verticalresponses VR
WHERE RespondentID IN
(
    SELECT RespondentID FROM verticalstackedresponses VSR WHERE VSR.Question = 'Brand     Aware'
)
```

The above I tried replacing with

```
SELECT 
    sum(VR.Weight) 
FROM 
    verticalresponses VR
    LEFT/INNER JOIN verticalstackedresponses VSR ON VSR.RespondentID = VR.RespondentID     AND VSR.Question = 'Brand Aware'
```

but unfortunately I'm getting different results. Can anyone see why and if possible advise a solution that will do the job just quicker?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Is the `WHERE` for the inner `SELECT` happening on an indexed column?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - not sure what you're talking about...

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz - the WHERE is not happening on indexed column and FYI - I have already tried replacing the WHERE with an AND VSR.Question = 'Brand Aware' on the actual join itself... Still no luck

Comment: How different? more than expected? duplicates?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @SebastianK - if WHERE isn't indexed, it needs to go through every row - a Table Scan - which could be killing your performance. Try adding Full Text Indexing to this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery

```
SELECT RespondentID FROM verticalstackedresponses VSR WHERE VSR.Question = 'Brand     Aware'
```

could maybe be returning multiple rows for any RespondentID, then you would get different results between join and in versions

Something along the lines of this may give the same results

```
SELECT 
    sum(VR.Weight) 
FROM 
    verticalresponses VR
JOIN(     SELECT distinct RespondentID FROM verticalstackedresponses 
          WHERE VSR.Question = 'Brand     Aware' 
    ) VSR
    ON  VSR.RespondentID = VR.RespondentID
```

Answer (score 1):

- A JOIN will multiply rows because it's an "Equi join"
- IN (and EXISTS) will not multiply rows because these are "Semi joins"

Either way, you need suitable indexes, probably

- verticalresponses, (RespondentID)
- verticalstackedresponses, (Question, RespondentID)

See [Using 'IN' with a sub-query in SQL Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966023/using-in-with-a-sub-query-in-sql-statements/6966259#6966259) for more

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to duplicates.  Try this:

```
SELECT sum(VR.Weight) 
FROM verticalresponses VR inner join
     (select distinct RespondentID
      from verticalstackedresponses VSR
      where SR.Question = 'Brand Aware'
     ) vsr
     ON VSR.RespondentID = VR.RespondentID;
```

You want an `inner join` because you want to filter the `VR` table.  A `left join` will keep everything in the first table.